# How to run a Maven enforcer rule before the Maven release prepare changes the pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-enforcer-plugin

I've created [a custom Maven enforcer rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html). This rule will check the content of the `<scm><connection>` value to ensure that it points to the `trunk` or `branches/*` (i.e. not a tag).
This enforcer is configured in the `pom.xml` like that:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-enforcer</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-release-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <releaseCheck implementation="my.company.maven.release.enforcer.MavenReleaseEnforcer"/>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Unfortunately, when we use it with the Maven Release plugin, the latter plugin changes the content of the `<scm><connection>` value during its [enter link description here]`prepare`[2](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) goal, so before the enforcer is effectively called. This results in a failure of my custom rule, as the `<scm><connection>` points to a tag at this time.

So my question: is there a way to force the enforcer to be called before the Maven Release plugin start to modify the `pom.xml`?

ps: the Jenkins job is divided into 2 steps: `mvn clean release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform`.

Answer (score 2):

when you call

```
mvn clean release:prepare
```

only the `clean` phase and the `prepare` goal is excuted.

You could use

```
mvn clean validate release:prepare
```

to include the `validate` phase or

```
mvn clean maven-enforcer-plugin:enforce release:prepare
```

to just trigger the enforcer plugin

Comment: Hello. Thanks. Note that the first solution does not work. Indeed, the enforcer will be executed twice (one for the `validate` goal, one for the `release:prepare` goal) and the second time it will fail. The second solution works, but I wanted to avoid such solution as it will require to change all my Jenkins jobs (or, if we forget to add the `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:enforce` goal, the enforcer rule will not be executed).

Comment: You might create a maven profile, that includes these two goals (`enforce` and `prepare`, eventually even `perform`) in the verify phase. So you could release `mvn -Prelease verify`